# Python : Using while loop 1-100 even number and sort 3 number on 1 line

Tags: python, while-loop

i'm got the code using while loop 1-100 result output is even number and sorting 3 number on 1 line.

My code:

```
i = 1
a = 100
n = ''
while i <= a :
        if i % 2 == 0:
           n = n + str(i)
           if i < 100 :
              n = n + ','
        i += 1
print(n)
```

How to do the result display is

```
2, 4, 6,
8, 10, 12,
14, 16, 18,
....
98, 100
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is add another condition where you check if `i` is the last element of your row. If so, append \n which results in a new line

```
i = 1
a = 100
n = ''
while i <= a:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        n += str(i)
        if i < 100:
            n += ','
        # needs to be added last
        if i % 6 == 0:
            n += '\n'
    i += 1
print(n)
```

since you want 6 to be the last index, when i=6,i%6 will result in 0.
The percent symbol works as a Modulo/remainder.

Note: make sure you have the right indentations, it seemed the code inside your `while` had an extra indent.